# Binding time and C assignment statement

Tags: c, variable-assignment, language-design

Given the following C assignment statement:

c = d * 120;

What is the binding time of:

a. The type of variable c?

b. The convention rule to write a variable?

c. The address of variable c?

d. The meaning of operator *?

e. The order in which two operands of operator * are loaded?

I know there are 6 possible binding times: language design time, language implementation time,  compile time, load time, link time, runtime.

My answers for the above questions:

a. compile time

b. language design time

c. load time

d. compile time

e. language design time

Could you please check my answers's rightness? Thank you :) .

Comment: The answer to question e) is that at language design time the decision was "the order is unspecified". That postpones the decision until compile time.

Comment: Kerrek SB: No, this is not a Turing test.

Comment: @Bo Persson, actually, that would make it "Language implementation time", with the possibility of the language being implemented in such a way that it is determined at compile time.

Comment: @Wiz Please note that [the homework tag is now being phased out and must no longer be used](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated).

Answer (score 4):

A. Compile time.

B. What is "the convention rule to write a variable"? What is meant by "convention" in this case?

C. Insufficient information for a specific answer. On  modern platform the "address" of a variable is determined by its location in [virtual] address space of the process. For a global/static variable it is determined at compile time or link time (depending on how you interpret the question) and on the linkage of the variable. For an automatic variable the absolute address is determined at run time, while the relative address inside the stack frame is known at compile time. You gave no specific information about the variable (global? local?), so there's no way to answer the question.

D. Compile time or language design time, depending on what is really meant by the "meaning of operator" here. The mathematical meaning of an arithmetic operator is determined by the language design. The specific version of overloaded operator (e.g. `int * int` vs `double * double`) is chosen at compile time.

E. This question is more vague than it seems. The order of loading instructions in the code   will be determined at compile time. However, the actual physical loads can be rearranged by modern processors at run time. What is meant by the question by "load order": order of loading instructions in the listing or order of physical run-time acts of transferring data?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
My lecturer's answer for E is runtime.
My lecturer's answer for D is compile time and language design time :) .

Comment: @AnT , Can you suggest us something (a link, a book, etc...) from where we can understand the binding times in general and reason in specific cases like your gorgeous answer here or we have to do experience about languages, compilers, ...:( ?